# how to write this query accordingly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

i need this query to run against 20 instances from main server that have linked server to those 20 instances.i want to change the [`@server`]  to the right instance via cursor and make the `SELECT` statement to work.

how can i write the query accordingly?

THX

```
declare @server varchar(50)

set @server = ‘servername\instnacename’

SELECT N'<TD>’ + ISNULL( + ‘<p class=”datarows”>’ + (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),column_name) from [@server].db_name.dbo.table_name),'<p class=”datarowserror”>Not Avail’) + N'</p></TD>’
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to DBA.SE. Do you simply need the select query text for each of the linked servers, or actually execute a query against them?  In other words, do you need to execute this part `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),column_name) from [@server].db_name.dbo.table_name` Or is creating the script for it enough?

Answer (score 0):

**If you only need the `SELECT` statements for each server**

```
SELECT 'SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),column_name) from ' + QUOTENAME(name) '.db_name.dbo.table_name;' FROM sys.servers where server_id != 0
```

**This gives me the statements for my two linked servers**

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),column_name) from [Server1].db_name.dbo.table_name;

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),column_name) from [Server2].db_name.dbo.table_name;
```

**If you need to execute the statements at once, you could use a cursor and dynamic SQL.**

```
DECLARE @server varchar(50)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE C CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT name FROM sys.servers where server_id != 0
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @server

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
SET @SQL =
'
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),column_name) from '+QUOTENAME(@server)+'.db_name.dbo.table_name;'
--PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @server
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```